# How can I convert a paid iOS game to a free game with in game purchases?

Tags: ios

I have developed a game for iOS that has had a decent amount of downloads, but I think I would get significantly more revenue if I were to convert the game to free to play, with in app purchases (especially since some competitors products are now free to download with in app purchases).

My question is what is the best way to go about converting to a free game with in app purchases without annoying the existing users?

On upgrading I'd like the people who previously paid for the app to have access to all the in-app purchases because I don't want to make them have to pay for content they previously had, and I don't want to make all the content (that is currently in the game) free.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely on topic.

Comment: @Duck: why not? Where would it be otherwise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered just making a different SKU?  Keep your paid version up there, and add a new one that's free with IAP.  It will be a bit more of a maintenance issue with future updates, but it seems like the fairest way to make sure that people who paid don't have to be in a situation where they have to do anything to keep their content.

Comment: +1 I'd like to add: call the free version "lite". Thus you won't risk upsetting people having the paid version who erroneously think that the "free" version is like theirs.

Comment: I think this may be the way to go.

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone, if this is the strategy you end up using be sure to mark my answer as "accepted"

Answer (score 0):

By including all content into the game but locking it off unless the user can authenticate against a server of yours, then pull down account information and unlock correct content.  There is no easier way because of the method in which you have sub

Comment: But the existing users have no account information that I have access to, as far as I know. Apples servers handle in app purchases.

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone: That's only half the truth - take a look at the Server Product Model. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1